# JavaScript - Using an if statement to check if a word is in a sentence

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

So here is my code

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data.products, function( key, val ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.products[i];
    if (obj.title == 'Hat') {
      var Imgs = '<div class="Hats"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
      $(Imgs).appendTo($(".HatsImages"));
    }
  }
});})})
```

So I'm stating if 'obj.title' (which is the sentence 'Plain Black Adjustable Hat') has the word Hat init then append 'obj.imUrl' to my HTML.

If I replace 'Hat' with 'Plain Black Adjustable Hat' it works but I just want to check for the word 'Hat' not the full sentence, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), but you have to keep in mind that it's case sensitive. An easy way to account for this is to convert the title [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) first.

For more control I would recommend using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Why? Consider where you have words such as "Chat" or "That", where "hat" is a substring. It's much easier to account for this with a regular expression and [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```js
let title1 = "Amazing Hat"
let title2 = "Amazing Cat"
let title3 = "Amazing Chat"

// Using includes
console.log( title1.toLowerCase().includes("hat") ) // true  :)
console.log( title2.toLowerCase().includes("hat") ) // false :)
console.log( title3.toLowerCase().includes("hat") ) // true  :(

// Using regular expression
console.log( (/\bhat\b/gi).test(title1) ) // true  :)
console.log( (/\bhat\b/gi).test(title2) ) // false :)
console.log( (/\bhat\b/gi).test(title3) ) // false :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `obj.title.includes(‘hat’)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `indexOf` , I believe that it the right tool for tha kind of situation

```
 $(function() {
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
          $.each( data.products, function( key, val ) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
            var obj = data.products[i];
            if (obj.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('Hat') >= 0) {
              var Imgs = '<div class="Hats"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
              $(Imgs).appendTo($(".HatsImages"));
            }
          }
        });})})
```